# Как подстроить размер текста под разные экраны?

Tags: ios, objective-c

У меня есть Label. Но на ipad и iphone он отображается по разному.
Нужно чтобы на ipad текст увеличивался, а на iphone уменьшался. Как это сделать?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: размер шрифта или размер UILabel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть три простых варианта как это сделать:

1. Если вы используете констрейнты, то привязать лейбл к правому и левому краю, и поставить растягивание.
2. Если вы используете autoresizing mask, то сделать то же самое, поставить ей привязку слева, и справа, и растягивание.
3. Самый простой вариант, прописать в коде все это относительно экрана, взяв за основу ширину экрана устройства, на котором будет запущена программа `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width` и уже от него выставлять frame лейбла.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже речь идет о размере шрифта.

Можно использовать size class для размера шрифта.
В атрибут инспекторе возле пункта Font есть +.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]